# How to access user objects within req in node express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using passport to authenticate user but having a hard time accessing it. I see the user object when I log the req object but I get undefined when I log or try to access req.user. I even tried to set the user object manually but I still get undefined. Is there a trick to access things within req or I'm missing a concept here? Here is what I have in my controller:

```
passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
  if (err) {
    return next(err);
  }
  if (!user) {
    return res.status(401).json({
       err: info
    });
  }
 req.logIn(user, function(err) {

  if (err) {
    return res.status(500).json({
      err: 'Could not log in user'
    });
   }
   req.user = user;
   console.log(req.user);
   res.status(200).json(req.user);
 });
})(req, res, next);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this ,

```
app.post("/url" , function( req , res , next){
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
      if (!user) {
        return res.status(401).json({
           err: info
        });
      }

      console.log(  req.user );

      req.logIn(user, function(err) {

              if (err) {
                return res.status(500).json({
                  err: 'Could not log in user'
                });
               }
        req.user = user;
        console.log(req.user);
        res.status(200).json(req.user);
        });
    })(req, res, next);

})
```

In this example, note that authenticate() is called from within the route handler, rather than being used as route middleware. This gives the callback access to the req and res objects through closure.